# maximal and minimal subgroups of torsion abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups

Is there a torsion abelian group $G$ for which exactly one of these conditions is correct:

1) every non-trivial subgroup of $G$ contains a minimal (non-trivial) subgroup of $G$.

2) every proper subgroup of $G$ is contained in a maximal (proper) subgroup of $G$.

?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) satisfies (1) but not (2) since it does not have a maximal subgroup.

Comment: Do you mean maximal (proper)?

Comment: @DerekHolt: yes.